# How to implement html partials in version 1.0.0 of Webpack file-loader where interpolate has been deprecated?

Tags: html, webpack, partials, webpack-html-loader

In version 1.0.0 of Webpack's [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader), the `interpolate` option has been deprecated, in favour of `preprocessor` (according to their changelog). `interpolate` enabled interpolation syntax for ES6 template strings, allowing you to import other html partials inside html files like so:

`<div>${require('./components/gallery.html')}</div>`

This was the de-facto way to implement html partials with html-loader, as several stack overflow suggested this solution.

However, now that that flag has been deprecated, I'm struggling to figure out how to enable this using the `preprocessor` option. The example in their github page comes with a handlebards implementation, but you didn't need this in the previous version - with interpolation the `require` syntax it all worked out of the box.

Anyone managed to replicate this html partials setup with the latest version of html-loader?